# Dynamic row index object not found in user-defined function R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to pass an integer ("i") to a function in which "i" is used as a row index for a data frame. However, doing this...

```
user_definedFUN <- function (i){
  ...
  result <- df[i, "col_name"]
  ...
}

x <- user_definedFUN(1)
```

...yields the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i, "col_name") : 
object 'i' not found
```

I'm certain this is a simple issue of how I am referencing "i" within the brackets (even if not simple enough for me to find a solution); however, I have provided additional details below if necessary.

The data.frame:

```
gen_name <- c("Boomers","Gen X","Millenials","Gen Z")
gen_years <- c("1946 to 1964","1965 to 1980","1981 to 1996", "1997 to 2011")
gen_xmin <- c(11, 9, 5, 2)
gen_xmax <- c(15, 11, 8, 5)
GEN_G.labels <- data.frame(gen_name, gen_years, gen_xmin, gen_xmax)
```

The data.frame contains information for four generations that will be used to plot rectangles as layers on a ggplot bar chart of populations by age.

The rectangles will be created by the following function that will be called from a loop and is provided the row index for specific generation (1 = "Boomers", 2 = "Gen X", etc.)

```
genlabelsFUN <- function(i){
  # return a geom_rect()
  rv <- geom_rect(aes(
       xmin = GEN_G.labels[i, "gen_xmin"],
       xmax = GEN_G.labels[i, "gen_xmax"],
       ymin = 1000, 
       ymax = 1100)
     , fill = "red")
  return(rv)
}

ggplot(...snip...) +
   ...snip... +
   genlabelsFUN(1)
```

The function works if a static index value is used. For example, 'GEN_G.labels[**1**, "gen_xmin"]' instead of 'GEN_G.labels[**i**, "gen_xmin"]' places a red rectangle between 11 and 15 on the x-axis at 1,000 on the y-axis with a height of 100. Although, the function is pointless without the dynamic aspect of "i".

The following image shows the output when using a static index value (Note: I'm using a different y-axis scale in my example above for simplicity). The final code will loop through each row of GEN_G.labels and run genlabelsFUN() to create a similar rectangle for each generation.

[image: population age chart with red box indicating boomer generation]

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Full ggplot

```
scaleFUN <- function(x) formatC( x / 1000, format = "f", big.mark = ",", digits = 0) #format as thousands with comma

ggplot(data = GEN_G.data_frame, aes(x = range, y = persons)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Persons (thousands)",
    labels = scaleFUN) +
  genlabelsFUN(1)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Reproducible example (functioning based on MrFlick comment below)

```
GEN_G.dataframe <- data.frame(
  range = c(1:21), 
  persons = abs(rnorm(21))*50)

GEN_G.labelsx <- data.frame(
  gen_name = c("Group A","Group B","Group C","Group D"), 
  gen_xmin = c(11, 9, 5, 2), 
  gen_xmax = c(15, 11, 9, 5))
GEN_G.labelsx$gen_name <- factor(
  GEN_G.labelsx$gen_name, 
  levels = GEN_G.labelsx$gen_name)


ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=GEN_G.dataframe,aes(x=range, y=persons),stat="identity") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = gen_xmin,
    xmax = gen_xmax,
    ymin = 175, 
    ymax = 180,
    fill = gen_name),
    data = GEN_G.labelsx)
```

Output from Edit 2 example.

[image]

Comment: If you supply the code for the example plot it would help. I think it is related to how things are evaluated inside the ggplot() call. The function appears to work on its own

Comment: Thanks - see edit above.  I'm not sure how to effectively share the data "GEN_G.data_frame". If it's required I will try to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use variables like `i` inside an `aes()`. Symbols inside the `aes()` are not evaluated until the plot is actually drawn. There's no way for R to properly capture the environment were `i` is defined that way so the value would have changed by the time the plot is drawn.

However, I don't really think a loop/function is even necessary. You should just be able to do

```
geom_rect(aes(xmin=gen_xmin, xmax=gen_xmax), ymin=1000, ymax=1000, data=GEN_G.labels)
```

to use a different data.frame for that layer. Then all the boxes are drawn at once without a loop.